# How would I remove / replace a HashMap value based off what the Value is?

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, user-input

I have a HashMap that shows a Car Parking space as the Key and a Vehicle Number Plate as the value, I have it so that the user inputs the number plate of the vehicle when they're retreiving their vehicle, I would then like to remove / replace the value for the number plate they just entered.

For example, the output would go from:

```
Parking Space: 1, Vehicle Registration: ABCD123
```

to this:

```
Parking Space: 1, Vehicle Registration: "Empty" / null
```

the tempVehicle.plate is a String that holds a user entered number plate.

```
    public int key = 1;
    HashMap<Integer, String> zone_1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public void addToZone1(Vehicle tempVehicle){
        if (key < 5) {
            zone_1.put(key, tempVehicle.plate);
            key++;
            System.out.println(zone_1.toString());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("There is no more room in this Zone!");
        }

    }
```

This is the only thing I have been able to come up with for this, I hope it's possible, I should of looked before hand I guess.

```
    public void pickingVehicleUp() {
        System.out.println("Please enter number plate: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String PLATE = input.nextLine();

        if (zone_1.containsValue(PLATE)) {

        }
    }
```

I was looking to add onto the if statement or change in completely, whatever I need to do to make this work, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key by value and if it is present remove it.

```
int key=-zone_1.stream()
      .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(PLATE))
      .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
      .findFirst()
      .orElse(null);
zone_1.remove(key);
```

But I would suggest to use PLATE as a key as you are doing operations based on it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your correctly, you would like to remove an entry from the map based on a value. In this case you can use `Map.values` and `Collection.remove` methods:

```
// {1=ABCD123, 2=XYZ8910} contents of the map

zone_1.values().remove("XYZ8910");

System.out.println(zone_1); // {1=ABCD123}
```

that's the simplest case. However, you might consider using plate as a key and parking space as a value if you are going to perform lookup by number plate. So instead of

```
  {1=ABCD123, 2=XYZ8910}
use
  {ABCD123=1, XYZ8910=2}
```

Which actually might be what you are really looking for.